# Faster way to calculate number of passes needed for bubble sort

Tags: sorting

Is there is a faster way to calculate the **number of passes** (**not** the number of swaps) needed to complete the bubble sort than actually doing the sort (as demonstrated in the code)?

E.g.

1, 2, 3 -> 1 pass

1, 3, 2 -> 2 passes

3, 2, 1 -> 2 passes

3, 1, 2, 4 -> 2 passes

0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7 -> 4 passes

Code in Python:

```
def count_passes(A):
    cont = True
    i = 0
    length = len(A)
    passes = 0
    while cont and i < length - 1:
        cont = False
        for j in range(length - i - 1):
            if A[j] > A[j+1]:
                A[j], A[j+1] = A[j+1], A[j]
                cont = True
        i += 1
        passes += 1
    return passes
```

Comment: If all keys were different, what about the difference in position between original and ordered?

Answer (score 1):

You sort the array say with quick sort, but also keep track of which position which array element is moved to.

Bubblesort can move an element at most 1 position towards the start of the array in each pass, not more. So you find in linear time the array element that was moved forward the most. The number of passes is the number of positions it is moved to the start, plus one for the last pass where nothing is moved.

And then you have to prove that in each pass, array elements at maximum distance from their final position at the front are indeed moved to the front, but that is easy.

Now if someone can post an answer for shakersort…

Answer (score 1):

Python version of what I think gnasher729 described:

```
def compute_passes(A):
    n = len(A)
    I = sorted(range(n), key=A.__getitem__)
    return n and min(max(j - i for i, j in enumerate(I)) + 1, n - 1)
```

Tests with various lists (showing the kind of order, whether all results were correct, and the results)

```
ascend   True [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
descend  True [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
constant True [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
random   True [960, 968, 935, 987, 943, 982, 981, 947, 945, 970]
```

Whole code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNNb4MwDL33V@RWsrIKtEtVjUlcJvW@G0KIgdumA4OSsK2a9ts7JwEGXbVcsJ33/PEc2rM@NviwaeXlIuq2kZrJHMumXixK2LOi6VBnba4UKC/m2wWjUzSoWcReZAfWF@QE1qoAD/pILhkEtzFHHiEfR1GBS0F1iPs4sO5Z6PJPajznlYIxuG8kOzGBpsUDeCNPGC7/Jdum9ixOTil7Mp9VmM5vzTHXfn9LpZxhA@kf7PXIbuxVxMLR7eccYxJ0J7EPD2rWbafhWk@cC7YjV9EioPTcnMh99gbnKF5n2QG00FBnGZ8WQatlLdCr80/vZCUxYgnf6QXY1SBzDd6Oc7ZioU8Uo5nrS4PSXpW/QkXjq3HLtHooqZlk/gqSbcpt9tikjlXaw@1sPX4@521GKwVqb7/8spW3m@@lP8kSDQ34g0HN2kaXuSoAS0InlSB/EMmVwN/3EQY85T2nhCsSvINUE4n/p9P@lc5RG36CKbsj4E242WUYBEHPc/@SYTlrXRwbUZAmk81G6Epn17mMSIvL5Qc)):

```
import random

def count_passes(A):
    cont = True
    i = 0
    length = len(A)
    passes = 0
    while cont and i < length - 1:
        cont = False
        for j in range(length - i - 1):
            if A[j] > A[j+1]:
                A[j], A[j+1] = A[j+1], A[j]
                cont = True
        i += 1
        passes += 1
    return passes

def compute_passes(A):
    n = len(A)
    I = sorted(range(n), key=A.__getitem__)
    return n and min(max(j - i for i, j in enumerate(I)) + 1, n - 1)

def test(label, As):
    counted = [count_passes(A[:]) for A in As]
    computed = [compute_passes(A[:]) for A in As]
    print(f'{label:8}', computed == counted, counted)

test('ascend', [list(range(n)) for n in range(10)])
test('descend', [list(reversed(range(n))) for n in range(10)])
test('constant', [[n] * n for n in range(10)])
n = 1000
test('random', [random.choices(range(n), k=n) for _ in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, the number of passes equals the amplitude of the largest element displacement required. The displacement is the difference between the index and the rank of an element. Finding all ranks is... a sorting operation. I don't see a possible shortcut (but I cannot swear).

Comment: I think you can do better for arrays with random elements. Say you have 1000 random elements. Quite likely that some random element is moved to the start by 900 or 950 positions. So if your first quick sort partition divides into 300 vs 700 elements, all the elements among the 700 on the right can only be moved by at most 700 positions and likely don't need examining. So you sort the left partitions first and may never need to sort many partitions at the right. On the other hand you may have a sub partition with no element originating far to the right, so you don't need to sort that..

Comment: @gnasher729: you should move that comment to your answer. Anyway, IMO one should answer for the worst case.

Comment: No, it was a comment to your answer. My answer basically was "You can do it faster than by simulating bubble sort" and that's enough. I usually don't bother with the worst case, but with the worst case that a user is likely to encounter. Which is obviously more than the average case, but often less than the worst case. And should probably be examined more. For example "Given an array of n items, and a quick sort implementation, what is the chance that the number of comparisons is twice, five times, or ten times more than the average?"

Comment: @gnasher729: this is the Computer Science site. And the question seems essentially of a theoretical interest.